# Return return-type of interface property based on a key as an argument

Tags: typescript

I struggle with Typescript once again.
My goal is to create a function for my e2e tests, which goes to a specific page in my app, reloads it and then returns the page-object of the specified page.

However it does not correctly determine the returned value. Right now, Typescript does not like that the `createTracksPage()` returns an object with less properties than the `createTracksPage()`

Furthermore, is there a more elegant way to solve this problem?

Here is a link to the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBATiArlAphGBeGBvAUDGKOAQ2AGsIAuGAIiNIpoBp8YIUooBLMAcytrtOPfs1wBfGMXShIUXLigBPAA4oYASQBKSVOixkUSkADNCqlKfi60C3NKVhgME4ifdw8NBwAqIADw%20MCgAHqhgACbo2jYQAHwAFKwANiDAxB5g1D4sAJTUAAoIALZc7P6seAQE9OQCWhyIcGA%20Fv7KalbAcCgZKD4kdQXEvChxrARC3Hz1jc2tau0WXT19AMoc0-zDo%20ME4gDaPgC6uHE4rAD0lzAAIiBsXBHqKCYmKMBQEAB03woEXDMCVS6UymAwWBoUxEEBouS8UCaYBg3V6qA2whmOxQCVyrEBMGBaQyXE8EMhtUY8J6iOaKNWqAGDAg2Nx-0IAAsEAB3GBgFC8gCicAQcASNBBJM8ZT5IFgXGKKmSKGKKDAqAicJg1xgADEQHA2CBVV5pJ4oByZREQGhZbBRrAiGiUBEpOgaPyAG4oOA0FEgZ4SOy4HUAYQZ6hUI3UIAARgArD6wVzuUmQBQpz5p%20nOplDaO4i4EGlInAwCZSag0YjMGCxquxv0V8RB3CZsGo9abGGs%20FVBGl7Dl6qV2g1ph1ht%20ifAKvAP3XACEMAAEtIYMUDZGEGo4NxbRbiMjKegS3TPcRkogUM2JEA)

```
const routes = {
  tracks: "tracks",
  settings: "settings",
} as const

type IRoutes = keyof typeof routes


async function resetTo<T extends IRoutes>(
  location: T,
): Promise<
  {
    tracks: ReturnType<typeof createTracksPage>
    settings: ReturnType<typeof createSettingsPage>
  }[T]
> {
  // Do side effects..

  if (location === "settings") return createSettingsPage()
  if (location === "tracks") return createTracksPage()

  throw new Error("location is not implemented") // For some reason this does not get treated as "never" code
}



// Create page object functions

function createTracksPage() {
  return { 
    a: "a", b: "b" 
    }
}

function createSettingsPage() {
  return { 
    a: "a", b: "b" , c: "c" //! Has more properties than tracks return value and TS does not like it
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would it be good enough to add overloads [like this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBATiArlAphGBeGBvAUDGKOAQ2AGsIAuGAIiNIpoBp8YIUooBLMAcytrtOPfs1wBfGMXShIUXLigBPAA4oYASQBKSVOixkUSkADNCqlKfi60C6UrDAYJxI+7h4aDgBUQACgAbEGBidzBqOhJyCBoASmoABQQAWy52AB4tDkQ4MG8LdOU1K2A4FFCUbyiKBOJeFAA+Btx7R2dXYDDPIV9A4NCucAihbj4Y+JgkkFSMrKgcvIKiyzNS8tQAZQ5R-lr6ppaIBycXN0Gwbp8QdO8YFAAPVDAAE3RtGwgGv1YgkLDqbwsCZTGYodKsOYLfJqQoWEplCpVBgQPaNGAAHxgkNy0LBy3h6xQW2EY1RzQIDRwrAA9NSYAAREBsLjPdQoEwmFCdCAAOh5CgIXDMfT+50wGCwNBGInGnnmuRgawqxJ2KLqKD8sVYQpgIoGHglkvo0TicoWioRqCR0VRmoFhAAFggAO4wMAoV0AUTgCDgfhov31FzSbpAsC4yRUARQyRQYFQz1NtJgADEQHA2NN1AiIB4oA6Q88QGhQ7B6rAiITnlJ0DR3QA3FBwGiKkCsiQKBTJgDClvUKnVMBAACMAFZc2CnTrnCAKKddJVW6pq+qaqkEMryi7YGCsAjECLEZgwYcRYctvcwcQd3DzsWLonbGW22Lrs0KneXg+0I9ME9nls-2ACJgBbWkAEIYAACWkGBknTfsEDUOBuBLfNiAuY0KHfC562IAJEBQS9r3EIA)?

```
async function resetTo(location: "tracks"): Promise<ReturnType<typeof createTracksPage>>
async function resetTo(location: "settings"): Promise<ReturnType<typeof createSettingsPage>>
async function resetTo<T extends IRoutes>(
  location: T,
): Promise<
  ReturnType<typeof createTracksPage> | ReturnType<typeof createSettingsPage>
  > {
...
}
```

(I'd make it a comment, but the link is too long.)

Comment: Yes this is enough and works well, thank you